# How does the question mark operator convert error types?

Tags: error-handling, rust

This doesn't compile:

```rust
fn foo() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    todo!()
}

pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    foo()
}
```

Nor does this:

```rust
pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    foo().into()
}
```

But this does:

```rust
pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    Ok(foo()?)
}
```

What is the mechanism behind the conversion that `?` does, and is there any better way to do this conversion than `Ok(...?)`?

Comment: Maybe you'll like the [`fehler` crate](https://github.com/withoutboats/fehler).

Comment: You probably want to convert the error, not the result that holds it - i.e. `foo().map_err(Into::into)` instead of `foo().into()`.

Comment: Absolutely agree. How are questions "How to properly handle errors?" and "Explain how deshugars this operator" same?
@Shepmaster

Comment: “How does the question mark operator convert error types?”; “What is the mechanism behind the conversion that ? does” - from the duplicate: “ Then the question mark operator will be able to convert any compatible error to one of these types because of various Into and From trait implementations.”

Comment: An off-hand comment buried in a long answer. The *title* is the same question, but if you actually read the question you can see he is asking how to convert from one error type to another, he's not asking the mechanism by which `?` does that.

Comment: Neither of the other "duplicates" talk about error type conversion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is something like:

```rust
// r?
match r {
   Ok(v)=>v,
   Err(x)=>return Err(std::convert::Into::into(x)),
}
```

So your last code is something like this:

```rust
pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  Ok(match foo(){
     Ok(x)=>x,
     Err(x)=>return Err(std::convert::Into::into(x)),
  })
}
```

Or this:

```rust
pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  let r: () = match foo(){
     Ok(x)=>x,
     Err(x)=>return Err(std::convert::Into::into(x)),
  };
  Ok(r)
}
```

**UPD**

As @Masklinn said, it uses From trait instead Into and [Try](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Try.html) trait too.
You can learn more [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1859-try-trait.md).
It is quite surprising because documentation for trait [Into](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) says:

> Prefer using Into over From when specifying trait bounds on a generic function to ensure that types that only implement Into can be used as well.

Finally, result code would look like this:

```rust
pub fn bar() -> anyhow::Result<()> {
  let r: () = match Try::into_result(foo()){
     Ok(x)=>x,
     Err(e)=>return Try::from_error(From::from(e)),
  };
  Ok(r)
}
```

Comment: FWIW the `try!` macro desugars to `From` rather than `Into`, I don't remember why exactly (possibly inference issues with Into?). And with [RFC 1859](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1859-try-trait.md) there's a second trait involved [around the `From` call](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1859-try-trait.md#desugaring-and-the-try-trait).

Comment: @Masklinn It is surprising for me because [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html) say `Prefer using Into over From when specifying trait bounds on a generic function to ensure that types that only implement Into can be used as well.` but you are right. I will update the answer.

Comment: Yeah if `Into` works it's generally recommended because `Into` is automatically implemented for `From`, but it doesn't always work so for something like a macro it's more risky.